# Adding Unit Tests to code not designed for it

Tags: c#, unit-testing

At work, we have a three-tier product. There is a client application which the users use and it queries data from a server which forwards those requests to a SQL database. We don't allow the client to have direct access to the SQL server.

The client product is what I'm wanting to unit test, but it has over 1.2 million lines of C# code and is a very old product. It was not designed with unit testing in mind and the lead developers for this product are generally opposed to unit testing mostly because of risk vs reward concerns, as well as how redesign would be required to reduce the amount of mocking that would need to be done. The redesign of these core, low-level client libraries and objects also has them concerned.

My philosophy is to certainly never neglect unit testing (because we'll *always* be too busy for it, and it'll *always* seem risky, and thus will never ever get done) and take an iterative approach to implementing unit tests.

I'm interested in hearing solutions to this situation. I'm sure many of you have encountered the situation of having to add unit testing into existing infrastructure. How could unit tests be added iteratively into the code base without hindering productivity and release cycles?

Comment: To my mind the risk is involved in *not* unit testing...

Comment: You can't change the past, why not just make a new test framework  create new tests as you make any changes to existing code or add new code? It's not perfect but as you start touching things over time the test suite will cover more and more of the code. Redesigning legacy code (that is stable) solely to support tests better seems likely to cause more problems than it solves, though, except to the extent that you are refactoring parts of it anyway.

Comment: Kind of curious what their perceived risks are? Finding bugs? (Seriously, I imagine it is most likely that they perceive the code to be bug free since it has run so long, so why "waste" the time writing tests to catch very little?) I'm definitely with Jon.

Comment: @pickypg I see the risk is in actually making changes to the code to facilitate testing only. I wouldn't refactor something of that scale that has been working just so I could test it better. Not to mention the enormous effort that could be invovled. But I would definitely start adding tests and doing whatever is required to make them work in the existing construct.

Comment: @jamietre I agree completely. We have the same approach where I work. Older, untested products are not rewritten for the sake of unit tests, but as they get refactored, then unit tests are written. Similarly, all new code has it as well. However, it was slightly implied that the risk versus reward included unit testing as a whole. It _is_ silly to rewrite something just to test it (you may introduce bugs of your own by destroying expected behavior), but new code certainly should have unit tests and old code should slowly start to get tested as it's refactored. We're in agreement. :)

Comment: Indeed. Having found myself in this situation, the temptation to refactor just *one little piece* so you can test (and reuse it better) is great... and I've shot myself in the foot by fixing stuff that ain't broke, or trying to generalize some legacy code, more than a few times. In old, non-modular code, what you think should be a tiny little change to one little piece can cascade into major problems very quickly :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In situations like this (and we've in fact been undergoing the same process with an old webforms to MVC transition) is to simply start testing new code. Over time, eventually that old code will be rewritten or refactored.

Before 'new' code is considered valid, it must be unit tested and code reviewed. Over time, eventually you will find that more and more of your solution is now under test, and less and less old code is being called.

Comment: This is what we do at work on an older product. New code is now unit tested, and old code is unit tested as it gets touched.

Comment: I like this response, but I think the biggest issue at this point for implementing the system of testing new code is that some parts of the old code need to be redesigned at a minimum to support a testing framework. There is just no getting away from that. It's the big hurdle, and in addition to that, finding time for getting that ball rolling under our "too busy" release schedule is yet another challenge at the management/business level.

Comment: Managers / sticklers always resist unit testing; it's their lot in life to prevent risk. The best argument I've ever heard is that it speeds up time to market; initially, yes, there is a slow down. But later on, when you don't have to worry about unintended side effects, it definitely does speed up development.

Answer (score 6):

I found Michael Feathers' [Working Effectively with Legacy Code](http://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/0131177052/ref=oss_product) useful when researching this topic.

Answer (score 2):

My experiences:

1. Implement a way for system (end to end) tests
2. When you add new functionality write system tests and design the new functionality with unit tests
3. When you change existing functionality write system tests beforehand
4. Do NOT try to rewrite existing modules for testing them with unit tests

This way you get unit tests for new functionality and create a (althought wide) security net for old functionality. Over time more and more parts of your system get system tests and (in percent) you get more coverage with unit tests. Redesigning old code just to get unit test coverage is to costly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm with your lead developers. It's 1.2 million lines of code which means which means that there is PLENTY of room for error when testing and redesigning. Its not designed for UT so it would probably take a non-trivial effort to rewrite the code so that it can be tested. I'm sure unit testing would be very time consuming. Plus, it's an old product which presumably means many of the bugs have already been found and fixed. *If it ain't broke, dont fix it.* Wouldn't you rather move on to the more interesting aspects of the project than testing and refactoring old code?

That said, if I absolutely thought it needed to happen, I would probably just write the tests for the pieces I touch, as I touch them. If I dont touch them, I dont test them.